# What's the password needed to ssh to Windows

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have 2 VMs, one is a Kali VM and the other is a Windows 10 VM that I've initialised with a generic key (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95922-generic-product-keys-install-windows-10-editions.html one of the keys from here to be exact).

I understand that I haven't actually activated Windows, and hence it doesn't have an Email associated with it.

I want to be able to ssh from my Kali VM to the Windows 10 VM (I also want to ssh from Windows to Kali, but I have been able to achieve that using downloaded OpenSSH-Server), however, when I try to ssh, it asks me for a password. I've tried the password associated with the administrator, however, that didn't work.

Edit: Here are the logs for the OpenSSH server from my Windows VM under debug1 symbol https://textdoc.co/xt3yuoFMXahq0Tcj .

Comment: I have Kali VM and a Windows 10 VM here.  I assigned passwords during installation. Once done you can easily map a folder in Windows from Kali - I am doing that here.  It is just like connecting real machines.

Comment: In order to SSH into a Windows installation you need the username and password, to a user profile, that exists on the machine itself. If the password is being rejected, you are likely, not using the correct syntax to connect to the Windows machine.  Provide the server logs associated with the timeframe while you attempt to make the connection to the server. Without detail information this question cannot be answered, nor can an appropriate duplicate be identified, the likelihood of this being associated with the system not being activated is actually fairly small.

Comment: what user are you using to ssh in to windows ... i.e. `ssh user@address` what is the `user` portion? if none, it uses whatever the current (client) username is

Comment: @Ramhound and @Jaromanda So, I use `ssh toto\administrator@address`  because that is what I get when I type `whoami` in powershell.

I was wondering, how would I be able to provide the logs, would I have to provide the logs using `journalctl` in Kali VM? Or is there something else that I've to do.

Besides, I also wanted to confirm, the password required to enter into the windows homescreen should be the password required by the ssh

Comment: @SauravChittal - My previous comment confirmed that fact. You need to provide the OpenSSH Server logs, so if the Server is running on the Kali VM, provide those logs otherwise they exist on the Windows VM not the Kali VM.

Comment: @Ramhound Do the logs I edited in the answer help? Or is there something else that I need to do?

Comment: You are attempting to log into Windows with  a user named `totoadministrator` is that the correct username for the Windows account? I already know it's not because the logs indicate it's an invalid user. This tells me the syntax your using to connect to the OpenSSH Server isn't correct. Just try `ssh administrator@address`, provided, Administrator is the actual user you want to use, which by default is **disabled**

Comment: Thank you soo much, that worked me.